# Free memory of a GpuMat

Tags: opencv, memory-management, cuda, out-of-memory, gpu

I am facing a problem with running out of memory on my CUDA device. I have detected the cause - in some of my member functions I'm returning a `GpuMat` constructed over data alocated by myself. Question here is - how do I free this memory?

```
class Test {
  GpuMat test() {
    float* dev_ptr = nullptr;
    cv::Size size(8192,8192);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_ptr, size.width*size.height*sizeof(float));
    return GpuMat(size, CV_32FC1, dev_ptr);
  }
}
//main
Test t;
while(true) {
  size_t free_mem, total_mem;
  cudaMemGetInfo(&free_mem, &total_mem);
  std::cout << free_mem << std::endl;
  cv::namedWindow("test", CV_WINDOW_OPENGL | CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
  cv::imshow("test", t.test());
  cv::waitKet(1);
}
```

You will see decreasing amount of `free_mem` each iteration (by the same amount).

---

What I've tried was to create custom allocator and `setDefaultAllocator` but it didn't work.

```
class CustomAllocator : public cv::cuda::GpuMat::Allocator
{
    float* m_ptr;
public:
    CustomAllocator(float* p) : cv::cuda::GpuMat::Allocator(), m_ptr(p) {}
    virtual bool allocate(cv::cuda::GpuMat* mat, int rows, int cols, size_t elemsize) override
    {
        return true;
    }
    virtual void free(cv::cuda::GpuMat* mat) override
    {
        cudaFree(m_ptr);
    }
};
// more or less looked like this...
GpuMat test() {
    float* dev_ptr = nullptr;
    cv::Size size(8192,8192);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_ptr, size.width*size.height*sizeof(float));
    GpuMat retval(size, CV_32FC1, dev_ptr);
    retval.setDefaultAllocator(new CustomAllocator(dev_ptr));
    return retval;
  }
```

Both [Allocator](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/df/d98/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat_1_1Allocator.html) and [GpuMat](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html) have not so well written docs so any help would be much appreciated.

---

**WHAT SEEMS TO BE WORKING**

```
GpuMat test() {
  float* dev_ptr = nullptr;
  cv::Size size(8192,8192);
  cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_ptr, size.width*size.height*sizeof(float));
  // do processing...
  // clone data so the GpuMat manages it by itself
  auto retval = GpuMat(size, CV_32FC1, dev_ptr).clone();
  // free manually allocated memory
  cudaFree(dev_ptr);
  return retval;
}
```

As I was writing it down right now I think that optimal would be to allocate GpuMat first and `//do processing...` using its `data`.

Comment: All of the mechanisms you are experimenting with rely on objects falling out of scope and triggering the class destructor. If you don't understand what that means, then you will need to revise some pretty core concepts in the C++ object model before going much further

Comment: Ok, you got me there, because I really did think that scope of GpuMat returned by test() is limited to one while loop iteration. And to be honest I'm still not sure why it's not like that... Can you elaborate?

Comment: You are creating instances of your class within the while loop. If you implement correct allocation and deallocation via object construction and destruction,(and you haven't but the answer covers that) , the objects need to fall out of scope to trigger destruction. That means the memory would be freed for all the objects within the loop after the loop exit. I don't think that is the behaviour you want

Comment: You could, of course, define additional scope within the loop to force destruction after each loop trip

Answer (score 2):

You're using the particular variant of GpuMat that involves a user-provided allocation.  Furthermore, `t` never goes out of scope in your `while` loop, so it's not clear to me that any implicit method would work.

Since you are providing that memory allocation with `cudaMalloc`, my suggestion is that it should be freed by you with `cudaFree`.  So, simplistically, make the `dev_ptr`  a class data member rather than an immediate/temporary variable, and provide a `Test::finish()` member function that tests this pointer for non-NULL and if so runs `cudaFree()` on it.  Of course if you wanted to handle via a constructor/destructor you might do it differently, and there are probably dozens of variations possible.

Here is one possible approach, coded in browser, not tested:

```
class Test {
  float* dev_ptr;
  public:
    Test() {dev_ptr = nullptr;}
    void finish() { if (dev_ptr != nullptr) cudaFree(dev_ptr);}
    GpuMat test() {
      cv::Size size(8192,8192);
      cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_ptr, size.width*size.height*sizeof(float));
      return GpuMat(size, CV_32FC1, dev_ptr);
    }
}
//main
Test t;
while(true) {
  size_t free_mem, total_mem;
  cudaMemGetInfo(&free_mem, &total_mem);
  std::cout << free_mem << std::endl;
  cv::namedWindow("test", CV_WINDOW_OPENGL | CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
  cv::imshow("test", t.test());
  cv::waitKey(1);
  t.finish();
}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to avoid the explicit call to `finish()`, and simply wanted to re-allocate, you could do:

```
class Test {
  float* dev_ptr;
  public:
    Test() {dev_ptr = nullptr;}
    GpuMat test() {
      cv::Size size(8192,8192);
      if (dev_ptr != nullptr) cudaFree(dev_ptr);
      cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_ptr, size.width*size.height*sizeof(float));
      return GpuMat(size, CV_32FC1, dev_ptr);
    }
}
//main
Test t;
while(true) {
  size_t free_mem, total_mem;
  cudaMemGetInfo(&free_mem, &total_mem);
  std::cout << free_mem << std::endl;
  cv::namedWindow("test", CV_WINDOW_OPENGL | CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
  cv::imshow("test", t.test());
  cv::waitKey(1);
}
```

Comment: Since I have more methods like test() in my class (upsss) I'd rather have a data-aware container which will release memory upon destruction and no member pointers. That's why I wanted to experiment with custom allocator which  would take care of it. Because I guess that eventually returned GpuMat goes out of scope on while iteration right? Is there an option to make the problematic pointer be limited to GpuMat lifespan? As some background explanation for such idea "Test" class has some allocated data on GPU and I'd like to return results of some processing.